# Django does not see the static files images

Tags: django

I'm trying to create an online store with Django. I want to add photos of goods, but Django for some reason does not see them. Please help to solve the problem.

Here is a screenshot of error:[image]

here is **settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles' 
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    '../static/products/media/product_images/',
)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    short_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s, %s" % (self.price ,self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Товар'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товары'


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/media/product_images/')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.id

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Фотография'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Фотографии'
```

main **urls.py** file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('online_shop.urls', namespace='online_shop')),
    path('', include('products.urls', namespace='products')),
    path('', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
]
```

html template

```
{% extends 'online_shop/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <section>
        <div class="top-section">
            <img src="{% static 'img/clem.png' %}" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                {% for product_image in product_images %}
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="product-item">
                            <div>
                                <img src="{{product_image.image}}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <h4>{{product_image.product.name}}</h4>
                            <p>{{product_image.product.description|truncatechars_html:80 }}</p>
                            <div class="price">
                                {{product_image.product.price}} ГРН
                            </div>
                            <div class="add-to-card">
                                <button class="btn btn-success">
                                    Добавить в корзину
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You have not mentioned the `STATIC_URL` in your settings and in `STATIC_ROOT` give a path that leads to 'staticfiles'

Comment: @Niladry Kar, it doesn`t help. Now doesn`t even see the other pictures

Comment: Add `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` with your `urlpatterns` in your urls.py. check docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Hi @РусланШамсутдинов, You are getting the error because you are getting the full path of the image. it should be `127.0.0.1:8000/static/products/media/product_images/..` and not the one shown in error image. Try to debug how you are getting that whole path instead of the desired one.

Comment: @Sam The problem is that I didn't write the absolute path to the files. I don't understand where this absolute path comes from

Comment: @РусланШамсутдинов : That's what you have to debug. Check `image` field in any `ProductImage` object. What is the path you are getting in that. I guess, image is storing the full path, but check it once.

Comment: @Sam Here is the ProductImage model:                                                                                                class ProductImage(models.Model):
 product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/media/product_images/')
 is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 is_main = models.BooleanField(default=True)
 created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
 updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

Comment: If you are getting relative path, then I guess you are missing this: use `{% static '{{product_image.image}}' %}` instead of `{{product_image.image}}`.

Comment: @Sam. {% static '{{product_image.image}}' %} Doesn't work too

Comment: @РусланШамсутдинов: You have already mentioned the model in the post, I can see that, but I am assuming from the error image that you are getting the full path in `image`.

Comment: @Sam. Sorry can you please tell me in which file I shound find the full path to image. I really not understand

Comment: Follow these steps:

1. Open shell: `python manage.py shell` 
2. Take an object of `ProductImage` after importing  e.g `from ..path/.. import ProductImage`
3. `productimage = ProductImage.objects.get(pk=1)`
4. `productimage.image`, you will get the value.

Do you have git repo setup for this?

Comment: Here the path to models.py.  C:\Users\tankr\shop\products. What shoud I write in shell? I'm trying to import but it not works in any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to do some modifications

> settings.py

```py
# prefix used in static files path rendering
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# store static files once execute python manage.py collectstatic
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')

# directories where static files are stored in the development environment
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

# prefix used upon uploaded images
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# where uploaded images should save
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

> urls.py

```py
# lets you have the ability to view images even in development environment 
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**update:**
Since you use `static/media/product_images/` as upload path, the uploaded files will be saved in 
`project-root-dir/media/static/products/media/product_images`

Hope this helps!

Comment: unfortunately it in not

Comment: ok, what is the pattern of the URL seems to be missing?
upload a new image with above settings, it should work

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by adding the following snippet to your urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('online_shop.urls', namespace='online_shop')),
    path('', include('products.urls', namespace='products')),
    path('', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: it doesn't help

Comment: try this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html